# Conditional execution for ESB action

Tags: jboss-esb

Is there a way in JBoss ESB so that an action can be conditionally executed.

My requirement is to conditionally transform an XML if the incoming XML has an attribute resubmitmode with tag value as true. Is there any way to do this with SmooksAction. I want to avoid the transformation if the tag value is false.
true

I did a lot of R&D but could not get this working. One alternative that came to mind was to add a transformation/XSLT rule but not sure if that would work

pasting snippet of jboss-esb.xml. smooks-res.xml contains the transformation rules.

```
 <property name="smooksConfig" value="/smooks-res.xml"/>

 <!-- property name="reportPath" value="/zap/smooks-report.html" / -->

</action>
```

I am using JBOSS SOA Enterprise platform 5.3 and ESB 4.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at the ContentBasedRouter, and then route based on your condition.     The **fun_cbr** quickstart should provide a decent example of how to do this.